# Iterate through all collections of all the dbs in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I need to Iterate through all the collections of each db. For each collection i need to do a collectionName.find() and print the json

Below is what i have tried:

```
#db_get_all_collections.js

db.adminCommand("listDatabases").databases.forEach(function(d) {
           mdb = db.getSiblingDB(d.name);
           mdb.getCollectionNames().forEach(function(c)  {
                   s = mdb[c].find();
                   prinjson(s)
           }
  });
```

I am dumping the output to a file as below

```
mongo admin -u <<user_name>> -p <<password>> < db_get_all_collections.js > output.json
```

However in output.json i see

```
MongoDB shell version: 3.0.3
   connecting to: admin

   bye
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  db.adminCommand('listDatabases').databases.forEach(function(d) {
    mdb = db.getSiblingDB(d.name);
    mdb.getCollectionNames().forEach(function(c) {
        var s = mdb.getCollection(c).find().toArray();
        printjson(s)
    })
})

mongo admin -u <<user_name>> -p <<password>>  db_get_all_collections.js > output.json
```